# How do backup applications detect renames?

Tags: synchronization, move, rename

I recently noticed that SyncToy (by MS) can detect renamed and moved files.

How do they do that? Is it only an elaborate guessing game based on file properties (last modification date, creation date, and file size)?

Answer (score 0):

One way to catch file renames, deletes and other is to use [FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) class (using dotnet framework).
If you develop an application (or a service) you can monitor file system changes and execute a custom action (with your code, so you can do anything  you need).
You can even set which directory monitor and if you want subdirs too.
Problems can arise with permissions on folders and files, but this is not part of your question :)

Comment: But that requires keeping your app on all the time :/

Comment: That's the reason I talked about a _Service_ ;) Anyway, yes, if you use that class your app MUST be running all the time... There are other solutions, but they need to _scan_ system (or a part of it according to settings) and find the differences with a previously saved _status_

Comment: Ho would that work? How can you tell a rename from a deletion + a creation?

Comment: @Clément: are you talking about FileSystemWatcher class or using other methods? With FSW you have `OnChanged` event telling you the reason of the change (Changed, Created, Deleted) and `OnRenamed` event. Using something different (offline) you could watch (for example) LastModifiedDate and/or CreationDate, but it's not enough...

Comment: I'm not interested in FileSystemWatcher. SyncToy doesn't use a service, but it detects changes and renames. I wonder how they do that.